# Pass Map values (created in javascript) to Action - struts2

Tags: java, javascript, struts2

I have a MAP object created in javascript. I have assigned values to this MAP in javascript. How can I access this MAP object in Struts2 action ? Please help me with this.

Here is the MAP object code in javascript -

```
Map map = new Object();
map['key1'] = 'value1';
map['key2'] = 'value2';
map['key3'] = 'value3';
```

Now I want the above 'map' object key and values in struts2 action.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to submit those values to the action.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Actually, what I'm doing is, Iterating through the Map values and adding the values to a string like this - key1~value1^key2~value2^key3~Value3 and storing it in a hidden field . Onclicking submit I'm accessing this hidden field in action and used 'Split' to split the string.

Now, there is a constraint with this, so I need to pass the values a s a MAP to action instead of String.

Comment: My question is how can I assign this MAP to form value in JSP and then access it in struts2 action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript code lives in the client side.i.e: The browser. Struts actions lives in the server side. i.e: your server (tomcat/jboss etc). So you need to send the data you've in the client side (inside the javascript object) to the server side. How you do this depends on your situation. If you have a submission taking place (via a submit button) then you can send along the information in your javascript object via that. One possibility is to create 'hidden' fields like below when submit button is clicked inside the 'form' being submitted.

```
<input type="hidden" name="key1" value="value1" />
```

Then in your struts2 action you could get hold of the parameter map and iterate through it finding out the values that were submitted.

**edit**

If you want to directly populate a Map in the action class. then use the following naming convention

```
<input type="hidden" name="valueMap['key1']" value="value1" />
```

In your action class if you have a `Map<String, String> valueMap;` field then it will get populated correctly

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Actually, what I'm doing is, Iterating through the Map values and adding the values to a string like this - key1~value1^key2~value2^key3~Value3 and storing it in a hidden field . Onclicking submit I'm accessing this hidden field in action and used 'Split' to split the string.

Now, there is a constraint with this, so I need to pass the values a s a MAP to action instead of String.

Comment: My question is how can I assign this MAP to form value in JSP and then access it in struts2 action ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

I'm unable to set the value to valueMap['key1']. Can you please help me on how to set the map values 

Map map = new Object();
map['key1'] = 'value1';
map['key2'] = 'value2';
map['key3'] = 'value3';

to valueMap['key1']

Comment: @user2894149 how are you currently setting the 'name' attribute of the hidden field.. simply setting the name attribute to "mapValue['key1']" would do.. can you post your javascript code

Comment: var map = new Object();
    <s:iterator var="prop" value="channelProperties">
    map['<s:property value='propId' />'] = '<s:property value='propDesc' />'
    </s:iterator>

The map is being generated based on the iterator. The hidden field name is set as you said. Now, I have a map object, how do I set it to hidden field value ?

Comment: @user2894149 you need to create separate hidden fields for each entry in the map. So if your map have key1/value1, key2/value2 (two pairs) then two hidden fields needs to be created. <input type=hidden name=valueMap['key1'] value=value1/> and <input type=hidden name=valueMap['key2'] value=value2/> and so on...

Comment: Thank you so much for the replies and solution. Your replies helped me a lot.. Thank you so much...